# How to write a custom Spock interaction mini-DSL for testing my mail sending?

Tags: groovy, spock

I am having trouble writing custom interactions for my spock tests that are succinct and readable.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class FunctionTestMailSpec extends Specification {
  ...


  def "process functional test email"(){

    ...
    stuff that processes the mail and ends up calling sendMailSvc.sendEmail()
    ...

    then: "mail should be sent to the expected address"

    // (A)
    1 * sendMailSvc.sendEmail(testMsg.sesMessageId, _ as Message ) >> {
      msgId, Message msg ->
      assert msg.subject == testMsg.variables.subject
      assert msg.to.flatten() == [mime.parseMailbox(keywordRealAddress)]
    }

    // (B)
    1 * sendMailSvc.sendEmail(testMsg.sesMessageId, _ as Message ) >> {
      msgId, Message msg -> assertMessage(
        msg, testMsg.variables.subject, keywordRealAddress)
    }

    // (C)
    1 * sendMailSvc.sendEmail(testMsg.sesMessageId, _ as Message ) >> {
      String msgId, Message msg ->
      new MessageAssertion().
        withSubject(testMsg.variables.subject).
        withTo(keywordRealAddress).apply(msgId, msg)
    }

    // (D)
    // GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@1e4c4fda' with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure' to class 'com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendRawEmailResult'
    1 * sendMailSvc.sendEmail(testMsg.sesMessageId, _ as Message ) >>
      new MessageAssertion().
        withSubject(testMsg.variables.subject).
        withTo(keywordRealAddress).&apply
  }

  void assertMessage(
    Message message,
    String subject,
    String[] to
  ){
    assert message.subject == subject
    assert message.to.flatten() == to.collect{mime.parseMailbox(it)}
  }
}

class MessageAssertion implements BiFunction<String, Message, SendRawEmailResult> {
  String sesMessageId
  String subject
  Mailbox[] to = []

  MimeUtil mime = new MimeUtil()

  def withSubject(String subject){
    this.subject = subject
    this
  }

  def withSesMessageId(String sesMessageId){
    this.sesMessageId = sesMessageId
    this
  }

  def withTo(String[] to){
    this.to = to.collect{mime.parseMailbox(it)}
    this
  }

  @Override
  SendRawEmailResult apply(String sesMessageId, Message message){
    if( this.sesMessageId ){
      assert sesMessageId == this.sesMessageId
    }
    if( this.subject ){
      assert message.subject == this.subject
    }
    if( this.to ){
      assert message.to.flatten().toArray() == this.to
    }
    return null
  }

}
```

(A) is the most straight forward way to do it, but it's a little noisy and will get messier as I start to want to test more values of the sent messages.

(B) is the best in terms of brevity, but it has poor readablity - having positional parameters instead of something that explicitly lists the name of each thing that's being tested is harder to read.  And I guess I'll end up needing a bunch of different methods with various parameters as I want to check different parts of the message for different tests.  That will start to get very confusing.

(C)  probably the best I can do in terms of readability.  Feels a bit redundant in terms of creating a closure to then directly call the apply() method, which is why I was trying to do something like (D) but fails with the listed exception.

Ideally, I'd like to write some kind of Groovy/Spock DSL magic that would make the interaction definition look something like:

```
1 * sendMailSvc.sendEmail(testMsg.sesMessageId, _ as Message ) >>
  new MessageAssertion().
    withSubject(testMsg.variables.subject).
    withTo(keywordRealAddress)
```

What do I need to do define a DSL that allows me to write interactions like that, or close to it?

Answer (score 0):

just an assumption

probably you can create a class like this:

```
class A{
    String name_ 
    A make(String name){
        this.name_=name
        return this
    }
    A rightShift(B b){
        b.greet(name_)
        return this
    }
}
//aka SendRawEmailResult
abstract class B{
    abstract def greet(String name)
}
//aka MessageAssertion
class C {
    def asserts=[:]
    Object invokeMethod(String name, Object args){
        if(name.startsWith('with')){
            asserts[name.substring(4)]=args
            return this
        }
        throw new Exception("$name method not supported for ${this.getClass()}")
    }
    Closure apply(){
        return {String x->
            println "assert for `$x`"
            if(asserts.Subject){
                println "assert Subject here"
            }
            asserts.each{k,v->
                println "$k : [${v.getClass()}] $v"
            }
        }
    }
    String toString(){
        return "*** ${this.getClass()}${asserts}"
    }
}

new A().make('world') >> 
    new C().withQwe('qwe123').withZte('zte456').withSubject('subj').apply()
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Have to add two ctors() form the Closure interface (something to do with delegation, "owner" and "thisObject").  But more importantly it fails with the same kind of error as (D), saying that it can't cast the close to a SendRawEmailResult (that's what the method being mocked, sendEmail(), is supposed to return).